# How can i fix this trigger it looks ok to me, i'm getting a PLS-00103

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

the following trigger code applies a discount to the bill after a certain amount of visits but i'm getting the following error PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:  := . ( @ % ; indicator

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECK_DISCOUNT
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF C_NO,BILL ON APPOINTMENT
  FOR EACH ROW

  DECLARE

  CURSOR C_APPTMNT
  IS
  SELECT C_NO,COUNT(C_NO) 
  FROM APPOINTMENT GROUP BY C_NO;

  V_C_NO APPOINTMENT.C_NO%TYPE;
  VISIT NUMBER(2);
  V_TEN NUMBER(3):=0.9;

  BEGIN

  OPEN C_APPTMNT;
  FETCH C_APPTMNT INTO V_C_NO,VISIT;

  IF VISITS = 3 AND :NEW.C_NO = V_C_NO THEN 
  :NEW.BILL := :NEW.BILL * V_TEN
  END IF;

  END;
  /
```

Getting a new error 
       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the
       following:
       . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod not rem
        <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like
       between ||
       The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.

Comment: yeah, i have changed the code but now i'm getting a new error

Comment: Either edit in the error, or possibly better to start a new question.

Comment: @Andrew edited already error occurs at line 19 fetch

Comment: add ; at the end of the :new.bill := :new.bill * v_ten;

Comment: @Andrew can't believe i never saw that, thank you very much

Comment: It's probably on-topic, in that it's answered in the comments. I couldn't find any other way to vote on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignment needs a `:`

```
:NEW.BILL := :NEW.BILL * V_TEN;
```

Comment: @Shimmerstrike you have 3 open questions, it would be good for you to go back and accept an answer on any question where a correct answer to you was provided.

Comment: 2) Missed semicolon after `:NEW.BILL = :NEW.BILL * V_TEN`; 3) Trigger defined on `APPOINTMENT`, executing `select` statement from the same table on which a row level trigger defined will raise `ORA-04091: table XXXX is mutating...`

Comment: Added semicolon :), copy pasted, fixed the assignment and totally forgot it.

Comment: @andrew lol not really just new to stackoverflow

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov i have modified the trigger but getting a different error.

Comment: @Shimmerstrike Would be better if you put that logic in a procedure. For example create a procedure AddAppointment(<<paraeters>>) and do all checks inside a procedure. And second approach would be creating a view `select * from appointment` and creating `instead of` trigger(it will allow you query the base table) and "insert into" view.